# Is it possible to record the screen to make a gif or mp4 file iOS?

Tags: ios, swift

I want to record my screen to make a gif or mp4 file, is it possible to do it. I found some where but they show to capture "outside" as a video, not everything I want. Just want to capture the whole screen for a time. May anyone give me some hints?

Comment: It's possible if you actually try something...

Comment: Try researching `ReplayKit`. Here is an [article](https://www.hackingwithswift.com/example-code/media/how-to-record-user-videos-using-replaykit) to get you started. If it looks like it is what you need, then I would read up on the [Docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/ReplayKit/Reference/ReplayKit_Collection/)

Comment: Yes, I found something helpfull here: https://www.hackingwithswift.com/example-code/media/how-to-record-user-videos-using-replaykit

Comment: Do you need to perform the recording on the device, or would it be enough to connect the device to your Mac and make the recording on your Mac? Because you can record the device's screen from the Mac using QuickTime Player.

Comment: I want to perform the recording on the device, and save it as a gif or mp4 file. How can? I have just try this link I post above, but it says "plugin com.apple.ReplayKit.RPVideoEditorExtension interrupted" and "Hub connection error Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=4097 "connection to service named com.apple.ReplayKit.RPVideoEditorExtension" UserInfo={NSDebugDescription=connection to service named com.apple.ReplayKit.RPVideoEditorExtension}"